# jQuery Error Messages

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Greetings,

I need some help resolving the 3 error messages that are appearing on my site.  If someone can help me out with these 3 error messages I will greatly appreciate it.

URL:
http://cms-prelive.myrtlewaves.com/home2.aspx

ScreenShot:

```
(error 1) $("#promo_go_btn") is null (line 4) - http://screencast.com/t/Wzdy21e4s1Zf
(error 2) $("a[href*=#]") is null (line 650 - http://screencast.com/t/Jo696r0700t   
(error 3) missing ] after element list (line 20) - http://screencast.com/t/xf0v3jjexS
```

Comment: Why is your page loading jQuery twice, at two different versions?

Comment: Anyway it looks like what's happening is that something is overwriting the global "$" variable.  The tangled mass of scripts involved is confusing; 2 copies of jQuery, various utilities, *and* MooTools ... not clear what's doing it.

Comment: Thank you for putting out the double use of jQuery, I thought I got rid of that. However on the other hand the MooTools is not the issue I know you can run both jQuery and MooTools together without any issues.  Even if I remove the MooTools script those same error messages occur.

Comment: Hmm ... well calling the real "jQuery" function (like in `$('#promo_go_btn'_)` will never return `null`.  That's certainly what I'd try to figure out via the debugger or something.

Comment: OK thank you. I'll keep trying. But just in chase you think I am out of my mind the reason I had those two jQuery scripts was because one was for Ajax and the other was the basic jQuery. For some reason adding that Ajax jQuery script helps with animating color.

Comment: HAHA... I am crazy I was thinking about something else. Thanks again for your help don't mind my last comment.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to simplify your JavaScript.** You probably didn't want to hear that, but I sincerely feel that it's the best advice I can give.

**Suggestions:**

- It seems you are using MooTools simply for your menu.  If that is true, then **ditch Mootools for jQuery** since you have a heavier jQuery usage.
- You have 18 scripts on your homepage alone.  **Keep your number of scripts to a minimum** because they stop other resources from loading.
- Load most scripts at the bottom of the page.

If you need help with any of this, feel free to comment and I'll elaborate.